# Syntax error on token(s) "product1. "VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token

Tags: java, android, variables, arraylist, declaration

I met this type of error when creating a new class. Below was my code:

```
package com.example.opener.test;

  import java.util.ArrayList;

  import Product.Product;

   public class ProductMgrStubs {
    /* Attribute */
       byte[] image1 = new byte[]{6,7,5,6,5};
       Product product1 = new Product("Product 1", image1, "Product 1", 0);
       ArrayList<Product> productList = new ArrayList<Product>();

       productList.add(product1); /* The error message popped out from here */


   }
```

Could anyone help me figure out what actually happened and some suggestions to fix this? I really appreciate your help

Sincerely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

```
productList.add(product1);
```

should be in a code block such as a method, constructor or instance initializer rather than the class block

Comment: It worked after I put it inside a method. Thank you very much Reimeus :)